# Animating sidebar with framer motion doesn't work when there is a child with layoutId

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

Exactly what I said in the title:

```
<motion.aside
  animate={{ width: state.expanded ? "256px" : "80px" }}
  className={cn(
    "fixed bottom-0 left-0 top-0 flex flex-col gap-10 border-r border-border bg-primary py-5 text-primary-foreground"
  )}
>
  <motion.div layoutId="test" />

  <button
    className="ml-5 mt-auto flex h-8 w-8 flex-row items-center justify-center rounded hover:bg-primary-hover hover:text-primary-foreground"
    onClick={toggleExpanded}
  >
    {state.expanded ? (
      <ChevronFirst className="h-4 w-4" />
    ) : (
      <ChevronLast className="h-4 w-4" />
    )}
  </button>
</motion.aside>
```

The sidebar does not animate when clicking the button. If I remove the layoutId from the motion.div it works as it should.